# Multiplicar matrices 3*2 y 2*2

Tags: python, numpy

¿Porque no puedo multiplicar estas dos matrices?

```
c = np.array([[1,0], [2,1],[3,8]])
d = np.array([[3,5], [2,3]])

print c*d
```

No entiendo que pasa, si lo hago con mi calculadora si que puedo ya que es una 3x2 y una 2x2.

Debería salir (si no me equivoco):

```
[[3 5]
 [8 13]
 [25 39]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con `numpy` puedes multiplicar matrices usando [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) de la siguiente forma:

```
c = np.array([[1,0], [2,1],[3,8]])
d = np.array([[3,5], [2,3]])

resultado = np.dot(c, d)

print(resultado)
```